# Drawing a polygon with one color for stroke, and a different one for fill?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgcontext

I'm having trouble with drawing some lines that are stroked with a color and then filling their insides (they make a polygon) with another one.

```
UIColor *houseBorderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(170/255.0) green:(138/255.0) blue:(99/255.0) alpha:1];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, houseBorderColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3);

// Draw the polygon
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, viewHeight-19.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 200, viewHeight-19.5); // base
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, viewHeight-119.5); // right border
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 120, viewHeight-119.5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, viewHeight-19.5);

// Fill it
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, (248/255.0), (222/255.0), (173/255.0), 1);
//CGContextFillPath(context);

// Stroke it
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

With the `CGContextStrokePath` commented out, I get this result:

[image]

But if I uncomment `CGContextStrokePath` and fill out the polygon, the color overflows the strokes:

[image]

How do you achieve a result like this (without having to redo the whole drawing procedure twice):

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

instead of

```
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

The problem is that both `CGContextFillPath()` and `CGContextStrokePath(context)`
*clear* the current path, so that only the first operation succeeds, and the second
operation draws nothing. `CGContextDrawPath()` combines fill and stroke without
clearing the path in between.

Comment: I don't want to sound demanding, but could you possibly elaborate to make a complete answer, because I don't quite get where should the `CGContextDrawPath()` should go?

Comment: Sorry, the answer was so short because I am on the phone :-) That call replaces both the CGContextFillPath and ...StrokePath.

Comment: This is the best solution in this case.

Comment: (Rolls eyes.)  Of course... DrawPath, rather than FillPath or StrokePath.  There's (Apple) logic in there somewhere !   Thanks for the tip...  I was having the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Using UIBezierPath you could do this:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(20, viewHeight-19.5)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, viewHeight-19.5)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, viewHeight-119.5)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(120, viewHeight-119.5)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, viewHeight-19.5)];

[[UIColor colorWithRed:(248/255.0) green:(222/255.0) blue:(173/255.0) alpha:1.0] setFill];
[path fill];
[[UIColor colorWithRed:(170/255.0) green:(138/255.0) blue:(99/255.0) alpha:1.0] setStroke];
[path stroke];
```

Comment: I know of UIBezierPath only from Apples examples, does it have any benefits as opposed to `CGContext` method outlaid in my question? @MikePollard

Comment: I think just all the usual advantages of using NSObjects rather than Core Foundation objects.

Answer (score 2):

When you stroke or fill the path in the context, the context removes the path for you (it expects that it's work is done). You must add the path again if you want to fill it after stroking it.

It's probably best to create a `CGPathRef path` local variable, build the path, add it, stroke, add it again, fill.

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 20, viewHeight-19.5);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path nil, 200, viewHeight-19.5); // base
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path nil, 300, viewHeight-119.5); // right border
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path nil, 120, viewHeight-119.5);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path nil, 20, viewHeight-19.5);

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextFillPath(context);

// possibly modify the path here if you need to

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `path` creation using the code I provided?

Comment: You'd use the [CGPath API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html) rather than [CGContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) to create the path.  However, in this instance, you should probably use `CGContextDrawPath()`, as the problem you’re having is indeed that the path is removed from the context by the `CGContextFillPath()` (and so you are stroking an empty path, which is why nothing happens).

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this concept, this makes everything much clearer with regards to CGContext! Thanks!