# Draw a colored triangle in ios

Tags: ios, colors, geometry, fill

I want to draw a triangle with a given line color, line thickness and fill color.
But some how I don't get the triangle to fill properly. Everytime the whole area around the triangle is filled also.

This is my code:

```
+ (UIImage *) drawColorTriangleWithBorderWidth:(int)Width Height:(int)Height R:(int)R G:(int)G B:(int)B A:(int)A BorderR:(int)BR BorderG:(int)BG BorderB:(int)BB BorderA:(int)BA Thickness:(CGFloat)thickness {

    if ( Width == 0 || Height == 0) return nil;

    float de = thickness/2.0;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(Width+de, Height+de));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);    

    CGFloat rr = 1.0*R/255.0; if ( rr > 1.0) rr = 1.0;
    CGFloat gg = 1.0*G/255.0; if ( gg > 1.0) gg = 1.0;
    CGFloat bb = 1.0*B/255.0; if ( bb > 1.0) bb = 1.0;
    CGFloat aa = 1.0*A/100.0; if ( aa > 1.0) aa = 1.0;

    CGFloat brr = 1.0*BR/255.0; if ( brr > 1.0) brr = 1.0;
    CGFloat bgg = 1.0*BG/255.0; if ( bgg > 1.0) bgg = 1.0;
    CGFloat bbb = 1.0*BB/255.0; if ( bbb > 1.0) bbb = 1.0;
    CGFloat baa = 1.0*BA/100.0; if ( baa > 1.0) baa = 1.0;

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, rr, gg, bb, aa);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, thickness);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, brr, bgg, bbb, baa);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, Width/2.0, de);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, de, Height-de);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, Width-de, Height-de);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, Width/2.0, de);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Note: `CGFloat rr = 1.0*R/255.0; if ( rr > 1.0) rr = 1.0;` can be more simple written: `CGFloat rr =  MIN(R/255.0, 1.0);`

Comment: Instead of the last `CGContextAddLineToPoint`, just use `CGContextClosePath`.

Comment: why do you use variables capitalized?

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the path after adding the different paths:

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, Width/2.0, de);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, de, Height-de);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, Width-de, Height-de);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: The `CGContextFillPath()` documentation explicitly states: "Quartz treats each subpath as if it were closed by calling CGContextClosePath." - Therefore closing the path should not be necessary.

Comment: Ok, the fill is necessary anyway

Comment: You have to use `CGContextDrawPath(..., kCGPathFillStroke)` if you want to fill *and* stroke a path (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462849/1187415).

Answer (score 1):

This works using the OPs posted code:

```
UIImage *image = [[self class] drawColorTriangleWithBorderWidth:100 Height:100 R:200 G:0 B:0 A:200 BorderR:0 BorderG:0 BorderB:200 BorderA:100 Thickness:3.0];

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:@"/Users/dan/Desktop/UIImage.jpg" atomically:YES];
```

Producing this image:
[image]

Comment: The `CGContextFillPath()` documentation explicitly states: "Quartz treats each subpath as if it were closed by calling CGContextClosePath." - Therefore closing the path should not be necessary.

Comment: @Martin But if I draw two sides of a triangle and stroke do I get the third stroked too? My reading is that `CGContextClosePath` is not needed for filling, intact that quote is only in the documentation for the fill routines. Does that mean that the third side of a triangle does not need to be added for a fill?

Comment: First of all, you have to use `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke)` if you want to fill *and* stroke a path (compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462849/1187415). You are right that closing the path is necessary for the complete stroking. But the reported problem in the question is that *"the whole area around the triangle is filled also"*. Perhaps `kCGPathFillStroke` does not close the path implicitly in contrast to `CGContextFillPath()`...